# Using Facebook API to access conversion statistics

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api, https, powerquery

I was able to pull campaign level facebook statistics using the following URL:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/act_<AD_Account_ID>/insights?access_token=<Access_Token>&date_preset=last_7d&limit=1000&time_increment=1&effective_status=ACTIVE&level=campaign&&fields=clicks,reach,impressions,spend,campaign_name`

However, I am having a difficulty adjusting the URL to pull conversion pixel stats such as Website Registration, Website Purchases, Website Leads etc..

Would appreciate some help.